# Wait/Continue in Alexa Skill Response

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing an Alexa skill which reads instructions to user. These instructions are long and normally consist of 8-12 steps with 1-2 lines per step.

I want to add **wait/continue** process in my skill.

**For Example:**

I want to implement a way that user can say wait, lets say on step 3 and wait for user to say continue to resume reading instructions from step 4.

**Problems:**

I could not find a way to make Alexa skill listen (to user input) while she is delivering response **(wait in this case)**.

I could not find any way to make Alexa wait for user to say something **(continue in this case)** to continue reading response without losing its session.

Comment: Will the user be answering in real-time (e.g. immediately after step 3?) or is this a situation where the user will be completing another activity and then need to return to the device?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the AudioPlayer interface. The algorithm will be something like this:

1. The user says a "pause". You turn him quiet music.
2. The user says "resume". You turn off the music and continue the story.

PS

I could not find another way to hold a user session for more than 16 seconds.